# My TFIve Model is deployed as a Flask API for training. It enters the model, as per my logging, but do not complete it! Works fine in local and docker

Tags: machine-learning, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have designed my ML model app as a Flask API. I am running my TFive model in "/train" route. In my local, I have dockerized my application and its working fine. While deployed as a Cloud Run in GCP, It enters the model training function, but do not complete it!. It takes around 35 to 40 mins in my local docker to complete and works fine.

Please see my environment settings,

In Local : Python 3.11.2 - 16 GB RAM Mac OS
In GCP Cloud Run : 8GB RAM and 2 CPU Cores with CPU allocated always

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.